# How to use generic in Scala from circe?

Tags: scala, circe

I want to use automatic generic marshaller to Json from circle:

```
def printTest[T<: Product](resourse: ResourcePartTest[T]): Unit = {
    import io.circe.generic.auto._
    import io.circe.syntax._

    println(resourse.asJson)
  }
```

But I can Exeption:

```
Error:(29, 22) could not find implicit value for parameter encoder: io.circe.Encoder[com.moex.regulatory.standards.intermediate.v23.ResourcePartTest[T]]
    println(resourse.asJson)

Error:(29, 22) not enough arguments for method asJson: (implicit encoder: io.circe.Encoder[com.moex.regulatory.standards.intermediate.v23.ResourcePartTest[T]])io.circe.Json.
Unspecified value parameter encoder.
    println(resourse.asJson)
```

Can I use automatic marshaller for Generic?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure how `ResourceParTest` is defined, but this should work by moving the generic derivation import outside the method and requiring an `Encoder[ResourcePartTest[T]]` as evidence:

```
import io.circe.Encoder
import io.circe.generic.auto._
import io.circe.syntax._

sealed trait ResourcePartTest[T]
case class Foo() extends ResourcePartTest[(Int, Int)]

def printTest[T <: Product](resourse:
                            ResourcePartTest[T])(implicit ev: Encoder[ResourcePartTest[T]]): Unit = {
  println(resourse.asJson)
}
```

Comment: I've found that for some sealed trait hierarchies the standard generic derivation just can't seem to be able to provide the necessary encoder/decoder, but the `extras` package generic derivation did do the trick.

Comment: @NimrodArgov This actually compiled properly when I ran it in IDEA.

Comment: Oh, it does work in most cases, just thought it worth mentioning.

Comment: @NimrodArgov Good to know.

Comment: sealed trait doesn't need, I add only (implicit ev: Encoder[ResourcePartTest[T]]), and It works.